# Differences between index-assignment in Numpy and Theano's set_subtensor()

Tags: theano

I am trying to do index-assignment in Theano using set_subtensor(), but it is giving different results to Numpy's index-assignment. Am I doing something wrong, or is this a difference in how set_subtensor and Numpy's index-assignment work?

What I want to do:

```
X = np.zeros((2, 2))
X[[[0, 1], [0, 1]]] = np.array([1, 2])

X is now:
[[ 1.  0.]
 [ 0.  2.]]
```

Trying to do the same thing in Theano:

```
X = theano.shared(value=np.zeros((2, 2)))
X = T.set_subtensor(X[[[0, 1], [0, 1]]], np.array([1, 2]))
X.eval()
```

Raises this error

```
ValueError: array is not broadcastable to correct shape
```

Comment: Same problem as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32226362/advanced-2d-indexing-in-theano-to-extract-multiple-pixels-from-an-image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This highlights a subtle difference between numpy and Theano but it can be worked around easily.

Advanced indexing can be enabled in numpy by using a list of positions or a tuple of positions. In Theano, one can only use a tuple of positions.

So changing

```
X = T.set_subtensor(X[[[0, 1], [0, 1]]], np.array([1, 2]))
```

to

```
X = T.set_subtensor(X[([0, 1], [0, 1])], np.array([1, 2]))
```

solves the problem in Theano.

One continues to get the same result in numpy if one changes

```
X[[[0, 1], [0, 1]]] = np.array([1, 2])
```

to

```
X[([0, 1], [0, 1])] = np.array([1, 2])
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that was a big help.